# Vugen Replay Error due to certificate : SSL protocol error when attempting to connect with host

Tags: sockets, ssl, loadrunner, vugen

am trying to record an HTTPS application , i have recorded it with Socket level and Winlnet level data with the auto SSL detect option uncheked.Successfully created the scipt. the script was created with a default web_set_certificate_ex function. But while replaying script was failing saying "SSL protocol error when attempting to connect with host "

Also tried enabling Winlnet instead of sockets in RTS - > Preference , got an error "INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_SELECT_CLIENT_CERT"

Answer (score -1):

GoTo Runtime settings preference and check replay in wintlet mode. it will work fine